# how to show uialertview in another thread in objective c

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios6

I created another thread and its functionality is working well. But only case is in new thread we cannot use UIControllers. As an example I couldn't use UIAlerview in new thread. How can I slove it?
My tried code is bellow.

```
- (IBAction)btnCopyImage:(id)sender
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(DownloadCheck) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

   // [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(DownloadCheck) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    NSLog(@"My name is ");
    int sum =0;
    for (int i=1; i<=1000; i++)
    {
        sum =sum+i;
    }
    NSLog(@"sum %d",sum);

}

-(void)DownloadCheck
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Download"];
    NSString* saveDialogURL = @"/Volumes/Inbox/7. Debugging and Troubleshooting.zip";
    NSString* fileNameWithExtension = saveDialogURL.lastPathComponent;

    NSLog(@"path %@ ",fileNameWithExtension);

    NSString *pathWithExtention=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", path,fileNameWithExtension];
    NSLog(@"path %@",pathWithExtention);

    //Remove existing file
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    [filemgr removeItemAtPath:pathWithExtention error:&error];

    //Copy file to i phone created directory
    if ([filemgr copyItemAtPath: saveDialogURL toPath: pathWithExtention error: NULL]  == YES)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download"
                                                            message:@"Downloaded Sucessfully"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertView show];
        NSLog (@"Copy successful");

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Download Faild"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertView show];
         NSLog (@"Copy Faild");
    }
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(DownloadCheck) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];` this cannot be used because it's working on same thread.

So what should I do by using same code?

Comment: use `performSelectorOnMainThread:` to show the alert.

Comment: And notifications to return a result, if needed.

Comment: Note: Just use performSelectorOnMainThead to show the alerts, not to do the other work.

Comment: Yash! thanks all.. Its fine.         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download"
                     message:@"Downloaded Sucessfully"
                    delegate:self
                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertView
         performSelector:@selector(show)
         onThread:[NSThread mainThread]
         withObject:nil
         waitUntilDone:NO];